# Append overwrites values even when copying list

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that contains a list at each key but when I try and append a new value to a list in a key it overwrites all the values in that list (obviously a reference issue) the thing that perplexes me is that I have tried all the different suggestions I could find on StackOverflow below:

1. Use [:] to create a copy of the list
2. Using copy and deepcopy

But my result is still the same, below is the affected code if someone could shed some light on my situation I would really appreciate it!

```
temp = defaultdict(list)
for vert in row:
    if vert > 0:
        temp[vert].append(row.index(vert))
```

This is the "vanilla" code where I haven't used any method to copy the list

Comment: Your example doesn't demonstrate the output you see and what you expected. How does that code overwrite anything? Also, `row.index(vert)` returns the *first* index, no the current index of the `vert` value in this iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is being overwritten. You are simply re-adding the same index again and again, namely the *first* index that has that `vert` value:

```
>>> row = [5, 5, 5]
>>> for vert in row:
...     print(row.index(vert))
... 
0
0
0
```

The value `5` is found at index `0` first, so `row.index(5)` always returns `0`, not `1` or `2` for later iterations.

If you wanted to add all indices, use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for idx, vert in enumerate(row):
    if vert > 0:
        temp[vert].append(idx)
```

which lets you track the iteration in the loop.

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head, feel like such an idiot many thanks for the help and the extremely swift response!